# Including token in http header for every request without using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, access-token

Is it possible to include json web token in http request header for every request?

I want to use server assigned token as a method to check the validity of user.

Comment: Seems difficult.. AFAIK You can't have common interceptor for all request coming from different frameworks..

Comment: Are you trying to use it to authenticate the web content? If your browser has to set the header, I think, cookie is the only way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor Yes. I am trying to auth the web content. If I were to save token into cookie, then what is a difference btw token-based auth and session cookie?